# "File not found" error when deploying to Windows Phone 8

Tags: deployment, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to deploy my first Windows Phone 8 app to my brand new Lumia 920, after getting everything up and running on the emulator, but I'm running into the following error during deployment:

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: AudioFilteringPhone, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
1>Deploying C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AudioFiltering\AudioFiltering\Bin\ARM\Debug\AudioFiltering_Debug_ARM.xap...
1>Connecting to Device...
1>Optimizing for device...
1>Installing the application...
1>Deployment of application to device failed.
1>Error writing file '%FOLDERID_SharedData%\PhoneTools\11.0\Install\{29b31259-9af9-47a5-9891-c3098315d3d8}\AudioFiltering_Debug_ARM.xap'. Error 0x80070003: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

If I manually try to deploy using the Deployment tool, I get the same error.  Does anyone know what the cause of this is and how to alleviate it?  This happens even if I just start a new WP8 app and immediately try to deploy it, so it's something wrong with my environment, not my application configuration.

Comment: Did you uninstall your app from the device? Did you restart the device? Did you uninstall and reinstall the WP8 SDK?

Comment: We have a winner!  There were updates that needed to install on the device, and updating/restarting fixed it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that there were software updates that needed to be installed.  If anyone knows a way to find out the names of the updates applied, I will post them here, otherwise all I can say is that I had to update to OS version 8.0.10211.204.

Comment: Reboot helped and indeed, I had a pending software update (Windows 10 insider build) on the phone.

Answer (score 11):

I had exactly the same problem, but solved it by simply rebooting the phone. No software updates were required.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  It worked for me.  Deployment started working after rebooting a phone running WM 10.0.15063.2.

Answer (score 1):

This also can be because of wrong USB cable or port. I have a long cable for charging which works with android devices, but doesn't with WP.
Or maybe using another USB port helped.